# JSF reset conditionally rendered input field

Tags: ajax, jsf, checkbox, conditional-statements, view-scope

### EDIT

### If have found the solution, but I need help understanding it. Questions are listed below

Whenever I try to reset the value of a conditionally rendered field, it reverts to a previously entered value instead of a null value.

The following is an explanation of the unexpected behavior:

1. checkbox is true --> textfield is rendered
2. enter 'test' into textfield
3. uncheck checkbox --> texfield is not rendered
4. click reset button --> checkbox value = true && textfield value = null
5. **expected --> inputtextfield with null value**
6. **actual --> inputtextfield with 'test' value**

### Simplified example

Form

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{testController.inputTextRendered}">
        <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form"/>
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:inputText value="#{testController.inputText}" rendered="#{testController.inputTextRendered}"/>
    <p:commandButton process="@this" update="@form" action="#{testController.reset}"/>
</h:form>
```

Controller

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestController implements Serializable {
    private boolean inputTextRendered = true;
    private String inputText;

    public void reset() {
        setInputTextRendered(true);
        setInputText(null);
    }

    public boolean isInputTextRendered() {
        return inputTextRendered;
    }

    public void setInputTextRendered(boolean inputTextRendered) {
        this.inputTextRendered = inputTextRendered;
    }

    public String getInputText() {
        return inputText;
    }

    public void setInputText(String inputText) {
        this.inputText = inputText;
    }
}
```

### side notes

- it's the omnifaces @ViewScoped annotation
- the process @form on the checkbox is necessary, because deselecting the checkbox should not reset the value of the textfield (only the button should reset it)

### Solution

This code works

```
<h:form id="testForm">
    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{testController.inputTextRendered}">
        <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form"/>
    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:inputText value="#{testController.inputText}" rendered="#{testController.inputTextRendered}"/>
    <p:commandButton process="@this" update="@form" actionListener="#{testController.reset}">
        <p:resetInput target="@form"/>
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

But this raises some questions:

1. Why do I need to add a p:resetInput when no validation errors even occur?
2. Why do I need to use the actionListener attribute instead of the action attribute?

Comment: Is there something missing?  Should it be : `<h:inputText rendered="#{testController.isInputTextRendered}" value="#{testController.inputText}"/>`.

Comment: ah yes, I removed some id's in my final edit and accidently removed the value as well. I'll update the question